# Run Drupal 7 Site on a Port Other Than 80 via Apache 2

Tags: apache, drupal, drupal-7

Does anyone know how I can run a Drupal 7 site from Apache2 on a port other than 80?  I've tried changing the base_url in the /sites/default/settings.ini file, and still no luck.  I have read that Apache needs to be updated somewhere, but I'm lost.

Ideally, I would like the Drupal site to run on something like this:

http://www.drupalsite.com:1234

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You need to change the port Apache listens on. In the main apache config you'll need to add `Listen 1234` and if you have a virtual host defined for your Drupal site change the listen port there too

Comment: Thanks.  How do I define a virtual host for my Drupal site?